# Hiding part of ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to plot two datasets on the same plot. The datasets have the same x-range. However, I want to show only parts of the plot.

A minimal example would be

```
    h = π/100.;
    i1 = ListLinePlot[Table[{i*h, Sin[i*h]}, {i, 0, 100}], PlotStyle -> Red];
    i2 = ListLinePlot[Table[{i*h, Cos[i*h]}, {i, 0, 100}], PlotStyle -> Blue];
    l1 = Graphics[{Black, Dashed, Line[{{π/2, -1}, {π/2, 1}}]}];
    Show[{i1, i2, l1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The output is the following

[image]

But, the plot I want is

[image]

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the `ColorFunction` option and set to `White` the parts you don't want to show.

Comment: Thanks, @b.gatessucks.  I am using 'i1 = ListLinePlot[Table[{i*h, Sin[i*h]}, {i, 0, 100}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x >= \[Pi]/2, Red, White]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];' now. It is almost there but I am getting a 'fade out effect'. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h = π / 100;
{d1, d2} = Table[{i h, #[i h]}, {i, 0, 100}] & /@ {Sin, Cos};
{ms1, ms2} = {{Opacity[0], Red}, {Blue, Opacity[0]}};
{i1, i2} = ListLinePlot[#[[1]], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   Mesh -> {{π/2}}, 
   MeshStyle -> None, 
   MeshShading -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
 {{d1, ms1}, {d2, ms2}};

Show[{i1, i2}, 
   GridLines -> {{{π / 2, Directive[Thick, Dashed]}}, None}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, kglr.

Comment: @Pratyay, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 4):

This is a hack may be as I do not see now a direct option to do this.

Combine the 2 list plots into one, using `Epilog` then use `Show`

```
red   = Table[{i*h,Sin[i*h]},{i,0,100}];
blue  = Table[{i*h,Cos[i*h]},{i,0,100}];
vLine = Graphics[{Black, Dashed, Line[{{Pi/2, -1}, {Pi/2, 1}}]}]; 
p     = ListLinePlot[blue[[1;;51]],
            PlotStyle->Blue, 
            PlotRange->{{0,3},Automatic}, 
            Epilog->First@ListLinePlot[red[[51;;-1]],PlotStyle->Red]];

moment=Show[{p,vLine},PlotRange->{{0,3},{-1,1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This was my first guess too. This is a simplified example. But, what I really have is a discrete data. Here the vline falls exactly on a x-data point which is not exactly my case. To clarify, I have data at x=1.2 and 1.3, and my vline is at x=1.26.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
h = π/100.;
a = Table[{i*h, Sin[i*h]}, {i, 0, 100}];
b = Table[{i*h, Cos[i*h]}, {i, 0, 100}];
α = FirstPosition[a[[All, 1]] - π/2, _?Positive][[1]]
i1 = ListLinePlot[a[[α ;;]], PlotStyle -> Red];
i2 = ListLinePlot[b[[;; α]], PlotStyle -> Blue];
l1 = Graphics[{Black, Dashed, Line[{{π/2, -1}, {π/2, 1}}]}];
Show[{i1, i2, l1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

?